# How to read big apache avro files

Tags: php, avro

I am new to apache avro. I had a task to read data from oracle DB and generate avro from that data. Then in second task read data from avro file and insert into MySQL DB.

I successfully able to complete both tasks for data upto 1,00,000 rows (3 columns). 
But when I increased rows to 1 million and 6 columns (small data in all columns), I still able to generate 33MB avro file. But in second task PHP avro library is giving error for `Allowed memory size of -- bytes exhausted` despite giving 1 GB memory limit.

```
$data_reader = \AvroDataIO::open_file($file_name);
// Read each datum
$i=0;

foreach ($data_reader->data() as $datum) {
```

After debug I found, foreach statement not able to execute and gave error. I am suspecting If it try to load all uncompressed data in memory which leading to error.

If their are better approach to read big avro files or I need to generate smaller avro files or I have to go for higher memory limits.

UPDATE : I checkout PHP Library code for method data where I problematic code found.

```
$data []= $this->datum_reader->read($this->decoder);
```

This would store all data in memory. An alternative update of this library at https://github.com/researchgate/avro-php uses PHP 5.5 yield, which I think should fix this issue. But currently I am using php 5.4 which do not have yield.